# javascript integration testing for one page applications

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, integration, phantomjs

I am currently developing a one page javascript application using Sinatra Ruby on  server side and Backbone.js, jQuery, jQuery UI for the client side.
The application main purpose is to allow a customer to view/edit different kind of items, each  item view being a more or less complicated form.

To make sure everything works right I am planning to do:

- unitary tests using QUnit
- functional/integration tests

What frameworks/tools do you recommend for integration testing in this case ? I started with Selenium but I didn't like it too much. I just started to look at PhantomJS and CasperJS and they seem pretty nice for basic stuff like navigating, clicking on links, ...

What's your advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what you didn't like about Selenium, but I'm guessing you are confident with JavaScript, so my recommendation would be to use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) as the main tool. It does work well with one-page web apps, and comes with its own testing tool. The code can still get a bit convoluted at times, when using nested `wait` clauses; deal with that by making sure you don't try to do too much in each test, and then if still complex, refactor. And don't forget design-for-testing: if your selector is horribly complex, consider adding a `<span id="xxxx">...</span>` around it, so your tests can go straight to it!

You can use CasperJS with both [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/). My preference is for SlimerJS currently, as:

- PhantomJS 1.x is stuck on an old WebKit (equivalent to Safari 5.1 and Chrome 13), so testing any more modern features is frustrating.
- SlimerJS can either work with the Gecko engine, or directly with a version of Firefox you have installed. This allows you to configure a Firefox profile with extra plugins, security certificates, etc.
- SlimerJS is written in JavaScript, so easier to hack if you have the need.

Once PhantomJS 2.0 comes out (around the end of 2013, hopefully), or if your site does not rely on any recent HTML5 APIs, you can run CasperJS twice, to get double coverage. (BTW, PhantomJS is naturally headless; SlimerJS needs to use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which is Linux or Mac only.)

What [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) gives you extra is you can control other browsers, IE in particular. (Though of course for IE you need to run a Windows machine.) Selenium, like SlimerJS, needs Xvfb to be headless (again, excluding Windows). (BTW, the Selenium docs [on supported browsers](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#browsers) has not been updated in ages, but I'm assuming later versions of each browser have at least the same support shown there.)

Comment: The first point against Selenium is its speed. It is very slow.

Comment: @user337620 My Selenium scripts are dominated by network access, so I've never perceived them as slow, except to start-up. I just realized your question was August last year, not this year! What did you end up going with, and are you happy with it?

Comment: I used CasperJS with PhantomJS. I will have a look at SlimerJS too.